# Authorizing users based on random database information in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on a system with a client API and a backend API. The client API has login system that interacts with a NetScaler that provides the client (user) with a JWT token.

The token contains one piece of information that is needed to authorize the user and that is located in the roles claims.

Secondly the user also sends in information regarding their location, this however is not in the JWT.

I need to create a authorization that checks the database and checks if the users role matches his location.

The DB table is simple and is just a location/role table:

```
Location | Role
---------+------------------
England    UserFromEngland
```

Is this possible to do or not? And if possible how, can I have a example please?

Comment: If the JWT is not encrypted you can simply decode it to read the roles then do your query as you would normally. You can inspect the token [here](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) and learn about how JWTs are structured [here](https://jwt.io/introduction)

Comment: Yes but  i want to make like a custom prefix based on the database matching like [Authorize(Role = "allowedUser")]

Comment: There are ways to go about that, I suggest you [implement a custom policy handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I will have a look at this thank you.